# maven-jar-plugin, include upper dir

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin, maven-jar-plugin

Build part of POM

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
               <classesDirectory>./</classesDirectory>
               <includes>
                  <include>*.wsdl</include>
                  <include>*.xsd</include>
                  <include>sources/</include>
                  <include>../configuration.doc</include>
               </includes>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
```

In target jar I have all wsdl from root dir, xsds from root dir and sources dir.
But no configuration.doc file in jar.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move the configuration.doc into the appropriate directory like src/main/resources.

Comment: Sou you start fighting against Maven but you will loose the combat. But furthermore why have you located the configuration.doc in a different location and the sources folder looks the same. The question is: Why don't you like to move it? Your personal tast or do you have a particular reason?

Comment: This config file lay with parent pom file in all projects. And many script use this config files. So i can't move it

Comment: Ok. Thats is by idea wrong. This means it's a resource which is used by others. Anyway. You can solve that problem by using the maven-assembly-plugin an repackaging the jar file and adding the configuration.doc file. You are working outside of the Maven conventions.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding the relevant folder from where you want the `.doc` to be picked up to your project pom using `maven resources plugin` - specifically the `<resources>` configuration - there are examples [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html).  This will make the contents available to the `jar` plugin.